# PXE boot an installation from 18.04 alternative ISO

Tags: server, 18.04, pxe

because the normal sever iso no longer lets you install raid disk in any sensible manner, I'm forced to try and get pxe booting working from the alternative iso and have hit a brick wall.

I followed the directions loosely from [pxe_boot_ubuntu_server](https://linuxhint.com/pxe_boot_ubuntu_server/) and managed to get the normal ISO to work fine (as long as I don't want raid), however, after do the same sort of thing from the alternative iso I get as far as keyboard layout and then fail miserably with an error saying "Your installation CD-ROM couldn't be mounted...".

The nfs share seems to be fine, my append line is as follows

```
append initrd=ubuntu1804/initrd.gz install=nfs://192.168.44.75:/netboot/nfs/ubuntu1804/ console-setup/layout=us vga=788 local=en_AU.UTF-8
```

But it seems to be unable to find the files for the install.

I did notice that there is no casper directory on this disk, rather an install directory and maybe I'm not using the correct initrd or vmlinuz files?

Thanks.